# Android Accessibility - how to set accessibility focus on some text when it appears?

Tags: android, talkback, accessibility

I have a page where the user needs to enter their email and then hit a button at the bottom to confirm. While confirming the email, there is a `ProgressDialog` overlay on the screen. When an invalid email is entered into the `EditText`, like just entering the letter "a", an error message appears below the EditText in the form of a TextView. I am trying to make this page more accessible.

My intended approach is to have TalkBack mode focus in on the error text when it appears. However, this isn't quite working. Instead, when the `ProgressDialog` overlay is dismissed, nothing on the screen is selected by Talkback, I notice that the "confirm" button still appears to be in a selected state, and I hear the app announce the app name again, as if the Activity is getting recreated (though it is not). Swiping right at this point will select the first view on the screen. It's worth noting that the confirm button does not appear to hold the "selected" state when talkback mode is not turned on, like it does when talkback mode is turned on.

Here's the code that I've tried:

```
private fun onServerResult() {
    ...
    dismissDialogOverlay()
    if (error) {
        showError(errorMessage)
    }
}

private fun showError(msg : String?) {
    mTvEmailError.text = msg
    mTvEmailError.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    mTvEmailError.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED) //want focus now!
}
```

I have also tried `mTvEmailError.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED)` and also tried pairing each with accessibilityEvent with `mTvEmailError.requestFocus()`. No luck.

What I'd like to have happen is for `mTvEmailError` to be the selected view in talkback mode. Instead, nothing is selected after the button press. It's as if Talkback mode gets completely lost after clicking on the confirm button.

Answer (score 1):

```
mTvEmailError.postDelayed({ mTvEmailError.requestFocus() }, 300)
```

//Explanation
 requestFocus function need to be called in a separate thread,if you call directly it will be called in the main thread,in main thread someother process may occur,if you call requestFocus() function traffic may occur,so we need to call in a separate thread with 300 milliseconds delay.

Comment: `requestFocus()` is not correct for TalkBack mode. Making a small change here, I call `mTvEmailError.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED)` inside the `postDelayed`. This solves the issue partially - the error text is read by the screen reader. However, the view is not highlighted by the screenreader and gesture navigation will begin from the top of the screen, rather than from the error message.

Comment: Additionally, even if I put a delay of 500 ms, the app name is announced AFTER the email error is read. I can not explain why the view appears to be reloading after the progressdialog is dismissed and why nothing is being highlighted by talkback mode.

Comment: Further investigation: I need to wait longer for this to work. I put a pause for 1500ms before trying to send the accessibility event and this seems to work. There must be some race condition here and I'm not sure what's causing it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue as OP, word for word.

Solved with this:

`editTextObject.performAccessibilityAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK, null);`

Now after the Dialog, the button that initiated the Dialog is unselected by Accessibility. Accessibility focus is on the `EditText` and TalkBack reads everything related to the EditText including the error message.

Comment: in my case Talkback is reading ProgressDailog STYLE_SPINNER as 0% any idea on this, how can we handle it.